# Is PeerJS, WebSocket, and/or Socket.io capable of matching users based on a property

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs, simplewebrtc

I have limited knowledge in this area. Is the following (*joke*) example possible to construct via Node.js packages?

E.g.  
 Clients open home page, they are asked '*Do you believe the world is flat?*'
Clients that click 'Yes' they are grouped in **Group Yes**, 
Clients that click 'No' they are grouped in **Group No**.

Next, clients from **Group Yes** are matched in a one-on-one room with clients from **Group No**.

If this is *possible*, how would the matching process occur? Would a lobby be required?

Comment: It definetly can. Lobby would be better sense of waiting. since a lobby exists on example then an admin should give the start and such =)

Comment: @halilcakar I appreciate your response. Would the be lobby be created via PeerJS or Socket.io?

Comment: Well I imagine socket.io lobby is easier. Since Peer need to create a connection to every single user in the lobby :)7